# Java Get all file names from a given directory, including subfolders?

Tags: java, file, directory

Basically traversing the entire folder structure.
for example, I have a music folder with albums as folders. I also have other miscellaneous songs in the music folder as well.

I have this but it only picks up the other music files and gives me a `FileNotFoundException`, with the reason being that access is denied to other album folders

```
    File[] files = new File("C:/Users/Mayank/Desktop/Music/").listFiles();
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        int check = (int) (Math.random()* files.length);
        isPlaying = false;
        mp3.close();
        mp3 = new MP3(files[check].getPath());
        mp3.play();
        isPlaying = true;
    }
```

**EDIT**: I see its a duplicate. thanks brain!

Comment: so it wont pick up say a .txt file? Also can you post the actual stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the issue is that you are trying to "play" directories (they are listed as well). Check `FileNameFilter`.

As for the generic issue, make a *recursive* method that lists all files in a directory, if it finds  a directory call the method again passing the new directory.